# How to write XML Code in Blockquote

Tags: discussion, tags

I am writing `meta` tags in `blockquote` but it is not displaying. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since SE supports partial HTML tags, it will try to render any HTML-like tags (e.g. XML), even if they are invalid. To prevent it from being rendered, you need to replace "<" character with `&lt;`.

---

```
> Text
>
> &lt;note>  
> &lt;to>Tove&lt;/to>  
> &lt;from>Jani&lt;/from>  
> &lt;heading>Reminder&lt;/heading>  
> &lt;body>Don't forget me this weekend!&lt;/body>  
> &lt;/note>
>
> Another text
```

will be rendered as

> Text
>
> <note>
>   <to>Tove</to>
>   <from>Jani</from>
>   <heading>Reminder</heading>
>   <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
>   </note>
>
> Another text

---

Alternatively, just use code-block inside the quote-block. In this case, the XML syntax can be pasted directly without needing to replace "<" characters.

```
> Text
>
>     <note>
>         <to>Tove</to>
>         <from>Jani</from>
>         <heading>Reminder</heading>
>         <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
>     </note>
>
> Another text
```

will be rendered as

> Text
>
> ```
> <note>
>     <to>Tove</to>
>     <from>Jani</from>
>     <heading>Reminder</heading>
>     <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
> </note>
> ```
>
> Another text